# How do I manually adjust the space between a symbol and the plus sign in amsart?

Tags: math-mode, amsart

I found that [`amsart`](http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/required/amslatex/amscls/doc/instr-l.pdf) seems to deliberately create space between a symbol and the plus sign. But sometimes I do not need the space, say

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\begin{document}
\[
f(x) \to l \text{ as } x \to a+.
\]

\end{document}
```

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Simplest: use \!

Comment: tex adds space around binary operators, but it does not add this space in subscripts or if the operator is at the beginning or end of the math list, so no space is added in this case. (In other cases you can use `{+}` to get a mathord plus rather than a mathbin one.

Comment: I see no space here.

Comment: Appreciated. I used a wrong example.

Comment: Again, there is no space around the `+` sign, because it is at the end of the math list. If the full stop would be inside the math list, then the `+` sign would be set as binary operator with additional space around. Then curly braces help to make `+` an ordinary math atom: `x \to a{+}.`

Comment: now as commented initially you could use `{+}` but the spacing and fonts for the rest of the expression are incorrect  `as` should not be in math italic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `+` in brackets `{+}` to treat it as ordinary letter rather than a binary operator.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  f(x) \to l \quad\text{as}\ x \to a{+}.
\end{equation*}
or better
\begin{equation*}
  f(x) \to \ell \quad\text{as \( x \to a{+} \).}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```